# Javascript function calling question

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible to do what I want? the `changeEl()` function is also in `fadeGall()`

```
    function initOpen(){

        $('ul.piple-holder > li > a, ul.work-holder > li > a').each(function(){

            var _box = $(this);

            _box.click(function(){

                //SOME CODE HERE TO RUN changeEl(0); on each _hold 
                //element from fadeGall()

            });

        });

    }


    function fadeGall(){

        var _hold = $('div.work-info');

        _hold.each(function(){

            var _hold = $(this);

            function changeEl(_ind){
                return;
            }

        });
    }
```

Comment: you need to re-phrase the question i don't know what your trying to do ... are you getting errors ?

Comment: yes you can call another function from inside a function

Comment: as it is now I get no errors. I need some sort of loop inside _box.click(function(){ that calls changeEl() on each _hold element or object or whatever it is called.

Answer (score 1):

No idea what you're trying to do, but if you are asking if it's okay to define a function inside of another one, sure, it is. Just be aware that the nested function won't be callable outside of the function it was defined in.

Answer (score 0):

You can nest a function within a function. The nested (inner) function is private to its containing (outer) function. It also forms a closure.

> A closure is an expression (typically
>   a function) that can have free
>   variables together with an environment
>   that binds those variables (that
>   "closes" the expression).
>   [reference](http://jibbering.com/faq/notes/closures/)

Since a nested function is a closure, this means that a nested function can "inherit" the arguments and variables of its containing function. In other words, the inner function contains the scope of the outer function.

To summarize:

- The inner function can be accessed only from statements in the outer function.
- The inner function forms a closure: the inner function can use the arguments and variables of the outer function, while the outer function cannot use the arguments and variables of the inner function.

The following example shows nested functions:

```
function addSquares(a,b) {
   function square(x) {
      return x * x;
   }
   return square(a) + square(b);
}
a = addSquares(2,3); // returns 13
b = addSquares(3,4); // returns 25
c = addSquares(4,5); // returns 41
```

Since the inner function forms a closure, you can call the outer function and specify arguments for both the outer and inner function:

```
function outside(x) {
   function inside(y) {
      return x + y;
   }
   return inside;
}
fn_inside = outside(3);
result = fn_inside(5); // returns 8
result1 = outside(3)(5); // returns 8
```